# Only center div if page is bigger than div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm using this style here to center a div as a background:

```
#example{
    z-index:-1; 
    width: 950px; 
    height:100%; 
    position:fixed; 
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    background:url(images/main_background_sidebar.png) repeat-y top center;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -475px;
}
```

That works fine, it stays centered and everything, but is there a way to stop it from staying centered if the page width is under 950 px? for example: if the browser window was only 800px wide, the left side of the background image would be stuck to the left side of the screen.

Comment: Is jQuery or simply JS a possibility? I could answer it with that. Pure CSS isn't really possible, unless you use media queries, which don't work well on IE from what I recall.

Comment: @OhMrBigshot: Post an answer, if it works well enough then I might be able to get away with using javascript.

Comment: Damnit. jsFiddle won't make it work for me

Comment: that `margin-left` is right? you are placing half of the div to the left?

Comment: Im using left:50% and margin-left:(half of div width) to center it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using CSS3 then you can apply [`@media`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/mediaqueries) rule. An untested possibility:

```
#example {
   /* Don't center it. */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 950px) and (min-device-width: 950px)  {
  #example {
   /* It's 950px or more! Let's center it! */
  }
}
```

Just read and play with it.

**UPDATE: How do I use this? Where do I put it, just in my `style.css`?**

> Media queries can be used in  tags, XML processing instructions, the @import at-rule, and the @media at-rule.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, how do I use this? Where do I put it, just in my style.css?

Comment: I updated the answer. In short, yes. Be aware of browser compatibility though.

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work. I know "It doesn't work" isn't a very good explanation of the problem, but I'm not sure what I can give you. Nothing changes at all when I implement it. Using Chrome for a browser.

Comment: @caesay, I updated the answer, I couldn't make it better since I can't make much sense of your posted CSS. You could create a jsfiddle, ofc.